# Casting int data type to array<int> in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to convert the datatype of a delta table in azure databricks notebook.Existing type is "int" and want to convert array.But getting below error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `F.array('landing_priority')`

Answer (score 1):

First import csv file and insert data to DataFrame. Then try to find out schema of DataFrame.

`cast()` function is used to convert datatype of one column to another e.g.int to string, double to float. You cannot use it to convert columns into array.
To convert column to array you can use numpy.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'X': [10, 20, 30], 'Y': [40, 50, 60], 'Z': [70, 80, 90]}, index=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])


# Convert specific columns
df[['X', 'Y']].to_numpy()
array([[10, 70],
       [20, 80],
       [30, 90]])
```